# Node Positioning on iPhone X

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift4

I am having a problem with some code not displaying properly on iPhone X, I've tested on all other devices and it works the way it should but won't work display properly on the iPhone X

```
    coinRect.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: -60, y: -20, width: 120, height: 40), cornerRadius: 5).cgPath
    coinRect.position = CGPoint(x: frame.maxX - 70, y: size.height / 2 - ((ceil?.size.height)! + 40))
```

I have included some screenshots to show the problem I'm having...

iPhone X rectangle is off screen:

[image: iPhone X rectangle is off screen]

iPhone 7 displays as expected:

[image: iPhone 7 displays as expected]

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running afoul of the scene not having the proper scaleMode assigned.  What scaleMode are you using, and how are you assigning the positioning of your screen elements relative to the scene and device size?

Another possibility is that the SKView is larger than the window; have you ensured that it has the proper constraints to peg the SKView to the size of the window?

Comment: Im using scale mode of scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

Comment: That's your issue, then.  .aspectFill scales up your scene, without distortion, to fill the viewport.  In your case, what it's doing is scaling the scene to fill the *height* of the screen.  Since the iPhone X has a different shape than the iPhone 7, that means the sides get cropped.  If the horizontal axis is what is important in your game, you could instead use .aspectFit, but then it would not fill the space vertically, and you'd need a strategy for what to do to fill that empty space.